# Coded UI Tests with x64 Projects

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mstest, coded-ui-tests

We have an x64 project that we'd like to do Coded UI Tests for. From what I've read, we need to change the host process for the Coded UI Test to run in a 32-bit process, but it seems the only way to do this is to change this project-wide. Is there a way to specify which tests to be run in which host processes? Or possibly simply which test projects/test class.

So far I've looked into creating a custom host adapter and declaring that on the tests, but have not had luck making this happen.

Is there any other way to do this then to manually switch the test host for the whole solution when wanting to run Coded UI Tests?

Comment: This is currently not possible. However, It would be interesting to see a solution to this problem.

Comment: I've been looking into making a custom test adapter and just declaring specific tests to use that adapter, but it's not been going well so far.